# How to set a color.Color value?

Tags: image, go, colors

I'm creating a bot of sorts with Go that takes a screenshot of my desktop, searches for a specific color RGBA, and when it finds a match it performs an action. Assuming I already have the screenshot, my program looks like this:

```
image.RegisterFormat("png", "png", png.Decode, png.DecodeConfig)
file, _ := os.Open("screenshot.png")
defer file.Close()

img, _, _ := image.Decode(file)

bounds := img.Bounds()
width := bounds.Max.X
height := bounds.Max.Y

for y := 0; y < height; y++ {
    for x := 0; x < width; x++ {
        color := img.At(x, y)

        if color == ? {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

The type of my variable color is `color.Color`, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to initialize a variable with that type. I need to compare it to a color with RGBA `{221, 223, 226, 255}`.

When I `fmt.Print(color)` at whatever pixel you get an output like `{178 180 181 255}`. How can I set a `color.Color` value to compare the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[color.Color](https://pkg.go.dev/image/color#Color) is only an interface that defines how to derive normalized R, G, B and A channel values. This means that for any given color.Color value, there are multiple different data types that it could contain, each having a different internal structure. In order to compare equality of different color.Color values, you can theoretically use `==`, but it only looks for *identical implementation*, not *equivalent representation*.  See this example:

```golang
import "image/color"
...
func colorEqual(c1, c2 color.Color) bool {
    r1, g1, b1, a1 := c1.RGBA()
    r2, g2, b2, a2 := c2.RGBA()
    return r1 == r2 && g1 == g2 && b1 == b2 && a1 == a2
}
...
        c := img.At(x, y)

        if colorEqual(c, color.RGBA{178, 180, 181, 255}) {
            // Do something
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Color` is an interface. You should use its `RGBA` method for the comparison. It returns the *red, green, blue and alpha* values - so compare them to your preset values as you wish.